# Why $\mathbb{E}\left[ X^{2}\boldsymbol{1}_{\{\mid X\mid > n^{1/3}\}} \right] = -\int_{n^{1/3}}^{\infty}x^{2}dF(x)?$

Tags: probability, integration, expected-value

Given a random variable  $X$ such that $F(x)=\mathbb{P}( \mid X\mid > x)$, for every $x>0$, the text I am reading wrote

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left[  X^{2}\boldsymbol{1}_{\{\mid X\mid > n^{1/3}\}} \right] = -\int_{n^{1/3}}^{\infty}x^{2}dF(x).
\end{equation}

$\textbf{Why is this true?}$

I know that

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left[  X^{2}\boldsymbol{1}_{\{\mid X\mid > n^{1/3}\}} \right] = \int_{-\infty}^{-n^{1/3}}x^{2}dG(x) +\int_{n^{1/3}}^{\infty}x^{2}dG(x),
\end{equation}
where $G$ is the distribution function of $X$.

Why can I discard the first term? Furthermore, why $dG (x) = - dF (x)$? I tried write $\mathbb{P}(X \leq x)= 1 - \mathbb{P}(X > x)$, but the absolute value gets in the way. I also don't know if I can write $dF$, since $F$ is not a distribution function.

Comment: No, on that interval the indicator function is equal to $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a way to resolve this. Do you agree?

Let $Y = \mid X \mid$. Thus, if $G$ is a distribution function of $Y$  then $G(y)=1-F(y)$  and $dG(y) = -dF(y)$.

Therefore

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left[X^2 \boldsymbol{1}_{\{\mid X \mid > n^{1/3}\}}\right]= \mathbb{E}\left[Y^2 \boldsymbol{1}_{ \{Y > n^{1/3}\}}\right]=\int_{n^{1/3}}^{\infty}y^2 dG(y)= -\int_{n^{1/3}}^{\infty}y^2 dF(y).
\end{equation}

Is this right?

Comment: Looks sound to me, but did you change the question to suit the answer?

Comment: I found an paper that used the same ideas and there was equality instead of inequality. It was the only change I made.

Comment: Ok, I guess that works out.

Answer (score 1):

First note that $F(x)=1-P(|X|\le x)=1-P(-x\le X\le x)=1-[G(x)-G(-x)+P(X=-x)]$ so that $dF(x)=dG(-x)-dG(x)-dP(X=-x)$ for $x>0$.

In the expression you know, the first integral where the variable of integration $x$ is negative is problematic. Thus take $x=-m$ to get
$$\begin{align*}\mathbb{E}\left[  X^{2}\boldsymbol{1}_{\{\mid X\mid > n^{1/3}\}} \right] &=\int_{\infty}^{n^{1/3}}m^{2}dG(-m) +\int_{n^{1/3}}^{\infty}x^2dG(x)\\&=\int^{\infty}_{n^{1/3}}x^{2}[dG(x)-dG(-x)]\\&=-\int^{\infty}_{n^{1/3}}x^{2}dF(x)-\int^{\infty}_{n^{1/3}}x^{2}dP(X=-x)\end{align*}$$

Comment: What do I do with the second term in the last equality?

Comment: I believe the second integral is non-negative so that you get the required inequality. Still working out how...

Comment: Excellent! You are helping me a lot.

Comment: @Wsa Is it known that $X$ is a continuous random variable...

Comment: Yes, $X$ is a real random variable.

Comment: @Shuham Johri,  I think I got it. I posted as an answer below.